# Single Sign On Using WebLogic Custom Authentication LoginModule

Tags: java, web-applications, weblogic

We are trying to do Single-Sign-On by reading user logged in account name and submit it to `Weblogic container` for authentication. We are using ping federator with that we are able to get all the user details and setting all the details in `Http Session` and trying to get it inside `Custom Authentication LoginModule`. I am unable to get the request inside my custom authentication login module. Can you please help on how to access `http request` in `LoginModule`?

Comment: try this code: HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) PolicyContext.getContext(HttpServletRequest.class.getName());

Answer (score 0):

In the callback list add this callback

> callbacks[1] = new weblogic.security.auth.callback.ContextHandlerCallback();

In your login method :

```
HttpServletRequest httpRequest = null;  
ContextHandler ch =((weblogic.security.auth.callback.ContextHandlerCallback)callbacks[1]).getContextHandler();  
if (null != ch) {  
   httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest)ch.getValue("com.bea.contextelement.servlet.HttpServletRequest");  
}
```

Comment: Great. It has worked perfectly. I am able to get request attribute and process it.